# Header of GetResponse API version-3 in C# (MVC-5)

Tags: c#, api, rest, curl, getresponse

I am a bit confused that when I get the error:

```
Problem during authentication process, check headers!
Unable to authenticate user, incorrect token
```

There is definitely something wrong with request header.

Can any one tell me the correct way of sending a request to `GetResponse` API?

I am using this way:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/campaigns", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", "api-key " + auth.myAuthorizationKey);
```

The header looks like this in request while debugging:

```
{X-Auth-Token=api-key d042eeae34ce076913681cc5c872741e2c5f88d2}
```

Comment: why are you adding `api-key` in token?

Comment: because it is in the [documentation](https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3) under Authentication Heading

Comment: I know there's something wrong with auth.AuthorizationKey Value. In api-key what do we have to pass TOKEN or API KEY ???
API KEY is the one shown on top of the Accounts->API & oAuth page.

Comment: then you have to pass `API KEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `APIKEY` instead `AuthorizationKey`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. As i was new to this API, i thought the AuthorizationKey must be used a token as the Documentation of GetResponse is not that good.